# Returns the cube of the sum of an input and 2

Tags: javascript

I'm taking online class to learn JS and I'm stuck.  The quiz is asking me to:

***Returns the cube of the sum of an input and 2.***

So I coded this:

```
var returnCubed = function(num){ return (num + 2) * 3;};
```

But it doesn't pass.  What else can I do to take in a parameter, add two to it, then cube it?  Or am I not understanding the directions?

Comment: num=num+2;return (num\*num\*num);

Comment: Cubing does not mean multiply by three.

Comment: Volume, edge, space diagonal or surface area?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var returnCubed = function(num){ 
       return (num+2) * (num+2) * (num+2);
};
```

`*3` will always multiply with 3.

Hope this can solve your problem.